# How to derive a regression formula

Tags: regression, econometrics

In this paper: http://www.nber.org/papers/w19774.pdf, (ungated version [here](http://economics.mit.edu/files/9800)) the author spells out the following regression (`equation 1` in the paper):

$s_{ij} = \alpha + \beta \bar{s_j} + \epsilon_{ij},$

where $i$ is individual, $j$ is school, $s_{ij}$ is outcome for individual $i$ in school $j$, and $\bar{s_j}$ is the average outcome for individuals at school $j$.  Note that $i$ is included in the average for his/her school, $\bar{s_j}$.

How does the author come up with the left-hand side expression for $\hat{\beta}$ (reproduced below)?  Also, what does $n_j$ mean?  And why does this equal `1`?  I feel like more steps would help me grasp this better.

$\frac{\sum_j \sum_i s_{ij} (\bar{s_j} - \bar{s})}{\sum_j n_j (\bar{s_j} - \bar{s})^2} = \frac{\sum_j (\bar{s_j} - \bar{s})(n_j \bar{s_j})}{\sum_j n_j( \bar{s_j} - \bar{s})^2} = 1 $

Note that page 195 of Mostly Harmless Econometrics has something very similar.

Comment: When I tried to open the paper, I just got "Online access to NBER Working Papers denied, you have no subscription".

Comment: Hmm - sorry about that.  I do think, however, that the paper is not necessary to answer the question.  I'll add a little more in terms of notation.

Comment: This appears to be ordinary least squares regression. You can find the formula for the slope estimate $\hat\beta$ written in many forms in many threads.  For instance, try [this search](http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=+regression+slope+formula). It is also one formulation of (one-way) Analysis of Variance (ANOVA).

Comment: Thank you.  I think that how to apply this formula is not as obvious to me as it should be.  If we have a usual regression: 
$y_i = \alpha + \beta x_i + \epsilon_i$,
then the formula is:
$\hat{\beta} = \frac{\sum_i (x_i - \bar{x})(y_i - \bar{y}}{\sum_i(x_i - \bar{x})^2}$.
The difficulty for me is how to translate this into the above case where our outcome variable has both an $i$ and a $j$ subscript.  Also, in the above equation, mathematically why does it equal $1$?  This is not obvious to me from a math standpoint - but the intuition is helped a lot by @Andy's answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As whuber pointed out, Angrist is just applying the formula for the OLS estimator to the above stated regression equation. From an interpretation point, regressing
$$s_{ij} = \alpha + \beta \overline{s}_j + \epsilon_{ij}$$
is the same as if you were to first regress
$$s_{ij} = a + \sum_j \delta_j D_j + e_{ij}$$
where $D_j$ are dummies for each school, and then you use the fitted values from this regression in
$$s_{ij} = \alpha + \beta \widehat{s}_{ij} + \epsilon_{ij}$$

To convince yourself, you could try the following code which is written for Stata but the logic works for your preferred statistical package and example data set:

```
// insheet an example data set
webuse nlswork

// generate the group-average of earnings by race
egen av_wage = mean(ln_wage), by(race)

// regress individual wages on the group wages
reg ln_wage av_wage

// now do the same thing with the dummy variable method described here
reg ln_wage i.race
predict wage_hat, xb

reg ln_wage wage_hat
```

The regression coefficients will not be exactly 1 due to the rounding errors that computers make but the logic goes through nonetheless.

Another way to see the tautological nature of this regression is given in the [published version](http://economics.mit.edu/files/9800) of Angrist's paper. Assume you have a mean zero random variable $y$, if you take the mean of $y$ conditional on another random variable $z$, i.e. $E(y|z) = \mu_{y|z}$, then the regression of $y$ on this group-mean variable must give a coefficient of one. Using a formulation of the OLS estimator (maybe one that you find more familiar) the corresponding regression coefficient of $y$ on $\mu_{y|z}$ is
$$\beta = \frac{E(y\mu_{y|z})}{\text{Var}(\mu_{y|z})}$$

Then take the numerator, apply the law of iterating expectations:
$$
\begin{align}
E(y\mu_{y|z}) &= E(E(y|z,\mu_{y|z})\cdot \mu_{y|z}) \newline
&= E(E(y|z)\cdot \mu_{y|z}) \newline
&= E(\mu_{y|z}^2) \newline
&= \text{Var}(\mu_{y|z})
\end{align}
$$
Substituting back into the formula for the OLS estiator you get
$$\beta = \frac{E(y\mu_{y|z})}{\text{Var}(\mu_{y|z})} = \frac{\text{Var}(\mu_{y|z})}{\text{Var}(\mu_{y|z})} = 1$$

Comment: Thank you.  This goes a long way towards laying out the intuition behind what is going on.

Comment: @Andy Please let me know if you know an answer this question https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/403715/how-to-derive-a-ranking-function-by-analysing-feature-correlations Looking forward to hearing from you :)