# Finding Regression Slope

Tags: regression, econometrics

This question is based on [How to derive a regression formula](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/125962/how-to-derive-a-regression-formula/126005#126005)

Start with a regression equation: $s_{ij} = \alpha + \beta \bar{s_j} + \epsilon_{ij},$

The goal is to get to this. *Update.  I figured this part out.  ***The remaining question is listed at the very bottom.

$\hat{\beta} = \frac{\sum_j \sum_i s_{ij} (\bar{s_j} - \bar{s})}{\sum_j n_j (\bar{s_j} - \bar{s})^2} = \frac{\sum_j (\bar{s_j} - \bar{s})(n_j \bar{s_j})}{\sum_j n_j( \bar{s_j} - \bar{s})^2} = 1 $

First, get $\hat{\alpha}$:

\begin{equation}
argmin_{\hat{\alpha}}~~ \hat{\epsilon_{ij}^2} = argmin_{\hat{\alpha}}~ \sum_j \sum_i (s_{ij} - \hat{\alpha} - \hat{\beta} \bar{s_j})^2
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\rightarrow \sum_j \sum_i (s_{ij} - \hat{\alpha} - \hat{\beta} \bar{s_j}) = 0
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\rightarrow \sum_j \sum_i \hat{\alpha} = \sum_j \sum_i (s_{ij}   - \bar{s_j} \hat{\beta})
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\rightarrow \sum_j n_j \hat{\alpha} =  \sum_j n_j  \bar{s_j} - \hat{\beta} \sum_j n_j \bar{s_j}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\rightarrow \hat{\alpha} = (1 - \hat{\beta}) \frac{\sum_j n_j \bar{s_j} }{\sum_j n_j} = (1 - \hat{\beta}) \bar{s}
\end{equation}

Next, get $\hat{\beta}$.

\begin{equation}
argmin_{\hat{\beta}}~~ \hat{\epsilon_{ij}^2} = argmin_{\hat{\beta}}~ \sum_j \sum_i (s_{ij} - \hat{\alpha} - \hat{\beta} \bar{s_j})^2
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
= argmin_{\hat{\beta}}~ \sum_j \sum_i (s_{ij} - (1 - \hat{\beta}) \bar{s} - \hat{\beta} \bar{s_j})^2
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
= argmin_{\hat{\beta}}~ \sum_j \sum_i ((s_{ij} - \bar{s}) - \hat{\beta}( \bar{s_j} - \bar{s}))^2
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\rightarrow   \sum_j \sum_i ((s_{ij} - \bar{s}) - \hat{\beta}( \bar{s_j} - \bar{s}))( \bar{s_j} - \bar{s})= 0
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\rightarrow   \sum_j \sum_i (s_{ij} - \bar{s})( \bar{s_j} - \bar{s}) = \sum_j \sum_i \hat{\beta}( \bar{s_j} - \bar{s})( \bar{s_j} - \bar{s})
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\rightarrow   \hat{\beta} = \frac{\sum_j \sum_i (s_{ij} - \bar{s})( \bar{s_j} - \bar{s}) } {\sum_j \sum_i ( \bar{s_j} - \bar{s})( \bar{s_j} - \bar{s})}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\rightarrow   \hat{\beta} = \frac{\sum_j \sum_i (s_{ij} - \bar{s})( \bar{s_j} - \bar{s}) } {\sum_j \sum_i ( \bar{s_j} - \bar{s})^2}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\rightarrow   \hat{\beta} = \frac{\sum_j \sum_i (s_{ij} - \bar{s})( \bar{s_j} - \bar{s}) } {\sum_j n_j ( \bar{s_j} - \bar{s})^2}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\rightarrow   \hat{\beta} = \frac{\sum_j \sum_i (s_{ij} - \bar{s})( \bar{s_j} - \bar{s}) } {\sum_j n_j ( \bar{s_j} - \bar{s})^2}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\rightarrow   \hat{\beta} = \frac{\sum_j \sum_i s_{ij}(\bar{s_j} - \bar{s}) - \sum_j \sum_i \bar{s}(\bar{s_j} - \bar{s}) } {\sum_j n_j ( \bar{s_j} - \bar{s})^2}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\rightarrow   \hat{\beta} = \frac{\sum_j \sum_i s_{ij}(\bar{s_j} - \bar{s}) - \sum_j \sum_i \bar{s}(\bar{s_j} - \bar{s}) } {\sum_j n_j ( \bar{s_j} - \bar{s})^2}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\rightarrow   \hat{\beta} = \frac{\sum_j \sum_i s_{ij}(\bar{s_j} - \bar{s}) - \sum_j \sum_i \bar{s}\bar{s_j} - \bar{s}^2 } {\sum_j n_j ( \bar{s_j} - \bar{s})^2}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\rightarrow   \hat{\beta} = \frac{\sum_j \sum_i s_{ij}(\bar{s_j} - \bar{s}) - \bar{s}\sum_j n_j(\bar{s_j} - \bar{s}) } {\sum_j n_j ( \bar{s_j} - \bar{s})^2}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\rightarrow   \hat{\beta} = \frac{\sum_j \sum_i s_{ij}(\bar{s_j} - \bar{s})  } {\sum_j n_j ( \bar{s_j} - \bar{s})^2}
\end{equation}

because $\sum_j n_j(\bar{s_j} - \bar{s}) = 0$

\begin{equation}
\rightarrow \hat{\beta} = \frac{\sum_j (\bar{s_j} - \bar{s})(n_j \bar{s_j})}{\sum_j n_j( \bar{s_j} - \bar{s})^2}
\end{equation}

Why does the last equality produce `1` in:

\begin{equation}
\hat{\beta} = \frac{\sum_j (\bar{s_j} - \bar{s})(n_j \bar{s_j})}{\sum_j n_j( \bar{s_j} - \bar{s})^2} = 1 
\end{equation}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are my steps (started from Line 8 of your steps finding $\hat{\beta}$). Hope there is no mistake.
$$
\hat{\beta} = \frac{\sum_j\sum_i (s_{ij}-\bar{s})(\bar{s}_j - \bar{s})}{\sum_j n_j (\bar{s}_j - \bar{s})^2} \\
\implies
\hat{\beta} = \frac{\sum_j \left[(\bar{s}_j - \bar{s})\sum_i (s_{ij}-\bar{s})\right]}{\sum_j n_j (\bar{s}_j - \bar{s})^2}
$$

$$
\because
\sum_i (s_{ij} - \bar{s}) = \sum_i s_{ij} - n_j \bar{s} = n_j\bar{s}_j - n_j\bar{s} = n_j (\bar{s}_j - \bar{s})
$$

$$
\therefore \hat{\beta} = \frac{\sum_j \left[(\bar{s}_j - \bar{s})\sum_i (s_{ij}-\bar{s})\right]}{\sum_j n_j (\bar{s}_j - \bar{s})^2}
= \frac{\sum_j \left[(\bar{s}_j - \bar{s})n_j (\bar{s}_j - \bar{s})\right]}{\sum_j n_j (\bar{s}_j - \bar{s})^2}
=1
$$

---

use $\implies$ (`\implies` in LaTeX) (which means 'implies' in mathematics) instead of $\to$